# HTML Media (Audio) player

Tags: javascript, html, web

I want to ask you how to code html audio (media) player, which is based on youtube video. So you get youtube video URL and add it to your website as audio media player (without video). Thanks. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

A tad of Googling always helps! [Useful links](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=youtube+as+audio+player&oq=youtube+as+aud&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60j0l2j69i64.2420j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Using [this website](http://www.labnol.org/internet/youtube-audio-player/26740/) yields the following code:

```
<div style="position:relative;width:267px;height:25px;overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:-276px;left:-5px">
        <iframe width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID?rel=0&autoplay=1"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you don't want your audio to autoplay, simple remove `&autoplay=1` from the `src` of the `iframe`.